# How to implement a navbar with HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

There are several examples of this on the net, using just HTML and CSS, or Bootstrap.  They often have examples like this:

```
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

What I'd like is for the navbar to not have to load on each refresh / link click.  Are the anchors in the example supposed to be replaced by links to other pages that include the full navbar source themselves?

What is a typical implementation, so that the navbar stays static?

How can I implement a static navbar between pages with HTML / CSS?

Comment: Look at the example at http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp - the tabs, this is an implementation where the pages does not reload. Is this what you meant? If so it's effectively one page with 3 pages of content on it, you just toggle what you see.

Comment: @SomeGuy - This is exactly what I was looking for, both the information and the example on the link.  Thank you for helping

Comment: No problem, I posted it as an answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the accepted answer is that the browser will have to load the content of all the tabs on page load. This may not be very good if your tabs have a lot of content and your users are using mobile devices. One way around that problem is using iframes. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a target="iframe" href="page1.html">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a target="iframe" href="page2.html">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a target="iframe" href="page3.html">Tab3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <iframe name="iframe" src="" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe(iframe) {
        iframe.style.height = 0;
        iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

This will load the content of each page into the iframe only when the link is clicked. Note that news.html, contact.html, and about.html have to be created as well.

Comment: a problem with this is that the iframe doesn't resize as I click on links.  Is this fixable?

Comment: @horsehair yea you can use some javascript code to run when the iframe loads/reloads to update the iframe height. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<ul class="w3-navbar">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="openCity('London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Put your content in to each list item above.

JS

```
openCity("London");

function openCity(cityName) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

First, call **openCity()** to open "London" (id="London).

Then call **open City()** with a different city name (id="Paris) when the user clicks on one of the buttons in the menu.

The **openCity()** function hides all elements (display="none") with the class name "city", and displays the element (display="block") with the given city id.

Sourced from http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp where you can find other examples too.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  Looks like people are trying to close this.  So many questions get closed and people without experience in the domain they're asking about end up without any hope.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMcKelvey I didn't realise that was allowed, have edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width:300px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

---

```
<ul>

  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with reloading the page content or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give you another possible solution. I'm putting it in a separate answer since it is a different idea.

Basically you can use javascript to fire an ajax request every time a link is clicked. The request will return the HTML content that will be inserted into the page. Here is a demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a target="#" href="page1.html">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a target="#" href="page2.html">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a target="#" href="page3.html">Tab3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="pageContent">

        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#nav li a").click(function() {
            $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Note I am using jQuery since it makes it much easier but the idea is the same if you want to use a different library or just vanilla javascript. Basically it attaches a callback function to the links' click event and that function calls jQuery's `load` function to fetch the content of the page and insert it into the div. I think this approach is much more common and you can find it in a lot of popular websites.